# AngularJS - What is the right way for this?

Tags: angularjs

I created a page, in which you can view lots of details on a user, in panels.

Every panel contains some information, received from a service, and sometimes has actions on it.

I have about 10 panels, and the viewer decides what he wants to see.

Is it right to make each of those panels a separate controller,
OR only panels with actions need to be in a separate controller, OR all the panels in one controller?

---

If every panel is a controller, and my code is this:

```
div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
  <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="historyPanel" ng-include="'panels/history.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to know if a panel is empty?

For example, I have an history panel, that I wanna show only when there is history to show, and I don't wanna show "No History", just wanna hide that panel.

But I do want to keep the panel code outside of the history.html view.

Comment: Curious, what version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @alphapilgrim Latest v1 (1.5.5)

Comment: Are you using an ng-repeat for panels? Be nice if you have a pen/plunker.

Comment: @alphapilgrim I hope I will be able to use ng-repeat for ng-controller, but I am not sure. There is no working code yet, just an awful code I want to delete and make new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider creating a directive for this.  You can either create a single directive that contains all 10 panels, and provide an attribute to specify which panel to show, or you could create 10 different directives.

Something like:

```
<my-panel panel="history" ng-show="userPanel.history.display"></my-panel>
<my-panel panel="settings" ng-show="userPanel.settings.display"></my-panel>
<my-panel panel="friends" ng-show="userPanel.friends.display"></my-panel>
<my-panel panel="music" ng-show="userPanel.music.display"></my-panel>
```

Then your scope controller might have something like:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.userPanel = {
        history: { display: true },
        settings: { display: true },
        friends: { display: true },
        music: { display: false }
    }
});
```

This way, you could load data from a service which has the user preferences for which panels are displayed.

Comment: Ok, that's I think better.. Is there a way to create different directives using ng-repeat? (If I do it with directives, Ill create 10 of them and not 1)

Also, in this example, how do I know if to display "history" for example? is there a way from the directive to do $scope.ngShow = false;?

Comment: The conditional display could also be handled in the directive, by putting the `ng-show` (or rather an `ng-if`) on the element the directive returns. And yes, the tags using a directive could be created by an `ng-repeat`, for example with `<my-panel panel="{{panelName}}" ng-repeat="panelName for panelName in panelNameList">`

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill use this, with transclude. I can just transclude a list item format, and handle the others on a switch.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, try not to inject $scope at all cost. :)

```js
function PanelCtrl() {
  'use strict';

  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.panels = [{
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Lucia Oconnor",
    "history": "my history"
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Stevenson Mcintosh",
    "history": "my history"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Spears Sims",
    "history": "my history"
  }];

}

function panel() {
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      //Depends what youd like to do with the PanelCtrl
      //'&': use a function on that ctrl
      //'=': two way data binding
    },
    controller: 'PanelCtrl as ctrl',
    templateUrl: './templates/panel.ng.html'
  };
}

angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('PanelCtrl', PanelCtrl)
  .directive('panel', panel);
```

This would be that template:

```
   //also if static content might want to use--one time bindings.
   // that would be ::panel.name
  <div class="panel panel-default" id="panel_{{panel.id}}">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{Panel.name}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body">{{Panel.history}}</div>
  </div>
```

This would be your html:

```
  //be sure to include track by, major perf gains.
 <div class="container" ng-repeat="panel in ctrl.panels track by panel.id">
    <panel bind="here" ng-if="ctrl.history.length"></panel>
 </div>
```

Comment: Same as for the other answer, coudln't the `ng-if` be handled in the template?

Comment: @Aaron in the ddo, or html?

Comment: HTML. No need to spread the view in two places : the fact it is displayed or not comes from the model, which should be represented as a whole by the template IMO.

Comment: @Aaron I think it might be best to do it on the directive, simply because were already using ng-repeat and want to stop the DOM from building those elements as soon as possible. Also now I'm wondering how far the request for those nodes get before the if statement kicks in.

Comment: You're not wrong, and actually it would be even better to filter `ctrl.panels` in the `ng-repeat`